# How to resize a view by dragging it's edges or sides in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ontouchlistener

I have an ImageView and I wand to resize it by dragging it's edges or sides. I have two problems.

1. I can drag just the bottom right corner.
2. When I drag the corner the entire ImageView scales.

How can I do it for every corner and how can I drag just one side or corner without scaling  the entire view?

For example with this code on dragging the bottom right corner I scale the entire view.

How can I set for example an anchor for every corner?
How can I just drag the corner or the side without scaling everything?

Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}


private static final int CIRCLE_SIZE_DP = 20;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Drawable circle = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.circle);

    int circleSize = dpToPx(CIRCLE_SIZE_DP);

    RelativeLayout viewToBeResized = findViewById(R.id.customView);

    ImageView bottomRightAnchor = new ImageView(this);
    bottomRightAnchor.setImageDrawable(circle);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bottomRightParms =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(circleSize, circleSize);
    bottomRightParms.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, viewToBeResized.getId());
    bottomRightParms.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, viewToBeResized.getId());
    viewToBeResized.addView(bottomRightAnchor, bottomRightParms);

    bottomRightAnchor.setOnTouchListener(
            new AnchorTouchListener(viewToBeResized, ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.status))));
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:text="Status"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></RelativeLayout>
```

AnchorTouchListener:

```
public class AnchorTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
private int actualWidth;
private int actualHeight;
private View viewToResize;
private TextView lblStatus;

public AnchorTouchListener(View viewToResize, TextView lblStatus) {
    this.viewToResize = viewToResize;
    this.lblStatus = lblStatus;
}

private int initialHeight;
private int initialWidth;
private int initialX;
private int initialY;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

    Log.d("Anchor", "Updating X & Y");

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lblStatus.setText("Action down");
            // Capture initial conditions of the view to resize.
            initialHeight = viewToResize.getHeight();
            initialWidth = viewToResize.getWidth();
            // Capture initial touch point.
            initialX = X;
            initialY = Y;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            lblStatus.setText("Drag finished x: "+actualWidth+" y:"+actualHeight);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //lblStatus.setText("Moving around");
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewToResize.getLayoutParams();
            // Compute how far we have moved in the X/Y directions.
            _xDelta = X - initialX;
            _yDelta = Y - initialY;
            // Adjust the size of the targeted view. Note that we don't have to position
            // the resize handle since it will be positioned correctly due to the layout.
            actualWidth = lp.width = initialWidth + _xDelta;
            actualHeight = lp.height = initialHeight + _yDelta;
            lblStatus.setText("Moving around x: "+actualWidth+" y: "+actualHeight+"");
            viewToResize.setLayoutParams(lp);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to only allow the the image to be draggable from the top left corner we can use the leftMargin and topMargin of the layoutParams of the image view.

```java
    var top = 0
      var left = 0

      var lastTouchX = 0f
      var lastTouchY = 0f
      var isDragging = false
      image.setOnTouchListener(object : OnTouchListener{
          override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
              val params = image.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

              top = params.topMargin
              left = params.leftMargin
              val width = image.width
              val height = image.height
              val x = event!!.x
              val y = event!!.y
              when (event!!.action) {
                  MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                      Log.d("left","$left")
                      if (x >= left && x <= left + 40 && y >= top && y <= top + 50) {
                          lastTouchX = x
                          lastTouchY = y
                          isDragging = true
                          return true
                      }

                  }

                  MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                      if (isDragging) {
                          val deltaX: Float = x - lastTouchX
                          val deltaY: Float = y - lastTouchY
                          val newLeft = left + deltaX
                          val newWidth = width - deltaX.toInt()
                          val newHeight = height - deltaY.toInt()

                //          Log.d("lasttou","$lastTouchX,$lastTouchY")

                          // Adjust the position and size of the image view
                          params.leftMargin = newLeft.toInt()
                          params.width = newWidth
                          params.height = newHeight
                          image.layoutParams = params
                          lastTouchX = x
                          lastTouchY = y
                          return true
                      }
                  }

                  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> if (isDragging) {
                      isDragging = false
                      return true
                  }
              }
             return true
          }

      })

  }
```

And I have used a flag isDragging which is true only when the user touch satisfies this condition (x >= left && x <= left + 40 && y >= top && y <= top + 50) the x coord must be between the left most margin and 40 coords after that and the y coord must be between the top most margin and 50 coords below that which would give us the top left top corner of the image and to resize only the top left corner i have tried something in the on_move event , I don't think it will fully satisfy you needs but try changing various params of the imageView until you find the perfect match.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work at all. It splashes instantrly all over the screen when I try to scale the right bottom corner. Is practically impossible to bring it back again. startScale value is impossible to initiate it in ACTION_DOWN so I initiate it in onTouch. What are dx and dx? I suppose _xDelta and _yDelta, or some other thing? With the initial code I'm able to scale everything by dragging the left bottom corner. I want to be able to do that with every corner individually. Can you for example show me how can I make an anchor for the top left corner instead of the bottom right corner?

Comment: @JulianDocev i have edited my answer please have a check.

Comment: with the (x >= left && x <= left + 40 && y >= top && y <= top + 50) condition there is no movement. When I take it off. The image is scaling whereever I touch it and slide. No metter if it is a corner or a center. When i do it from the top left corner it do it correctly. From the other corners or places it scales but diferently. Is this what the params.leftMargin and params.TopMargin are doing? I think I've got the idea. I did it with my code by just changing the side of my anchor.

Comment: But what if I want to have four anchors. For every side of the view? Do I need 4 onTouchListeners for every anchor or there is a better way?

Comment: @JulianDocev yeah, try implementing 4 onTouchListeners and to scale the respective sides you use params of all the margins (left,right,top,bottom) try this and let us know the output.

Comment: Works perfect like this. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question related to this one. When I use this code and I drag the top left edge the entire view scales in size. I mean if I drag left it goes right too. If I go up, it changes the coordinates for the down too. You know what I mean?  How can I bloque the right side when i drag the left side and the bottom when I drag the top?